# How to store data to an array inside foreach loop in Laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have a collection of **$linesheetItems**, now I need to loop these $linesheetItems inside a **foreach loop** and store a seasons array by using line sheet item's season code  **($linesheetItem['season'])**. But according to my current code, it returns an empty array.

**Code:**

```
$seasons = [];
foreach($linesheetItems as $linesheetItem) {
    $seasons = Season::where('code', $linesheetItem['season'])->get();
}

dd($seasons);
```

How to achieve this, and what are the modifications should I do to my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are overriding the `$seasons` variable each time the loop runs. In order to add an item to an array you have to set `$seasons[] = Season::where('code', $linesheetItem['season'])->get();`. This will always push a new item into the array. If you want to have custom keys on the array, you can do `$seasons['your-key'] = Season::where('code', $linesheetItem['season'])->get();`